# Number-count-up animation in a non-blocking way

Tags: javascript, ios, multithreading, animation, titanium

I am trying to count a number up to a certain target value in an animation-like style. The environment is Titanium on iOS. I do that as follows.

```js
function countNumberUp(label) {
    label.currentVal = label.currentVal ? label.currentVal : 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (label.currentVal < label.targetVal) {
            label.currentVal += 1;
            label.setText(label.currentVal);
            countNumberUp(label);
        }
    }, 5);

}
```

`label` is an instance of `Ti.UI.Label`.

First problem I see is that the label.setText()-method is veeery slow. Would be cool if the number counts up in a rush but it's only like 5 steps per second even if I vary the second parameter of setTimeout().

The other thing is that the animation totally blocks die Main/UI thread of iOS and the UI hardly accepts any actions until the animation has finished. Seems like setTimeout does not run in a seperate thread.

Does anyone of you know a better way to do this?

Btw. I have also tried setInterval() but it doesn't seem any better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
function countNumberUp(label){

    var interval = setInterval(function(){

        if(label.currentVal==label.targetVal){
          clearInterval(interval);  
        }else{
          label.text=label.currentVal;
          label.currentVal++;
        }
        //remove self-calling contNumberUp(label);
    }, 50);
//5ms delay its cause bad performance
}
```